# incorrect layout of navigation pane

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have created a navigation pane in `Bootstrap 4`. I want that for screens smaller than `sm`, the navigation panes are shown vertically instead of horizontally. It works but I notice that the content of the tab is shown after all the tab headings (please see pic below). How could I change the layout such that on clicking a tab, the content of that tab is shown below it and then the remaining tab headings are displayed

[image]

I want `Lorem Ipsum personal` to show before `prints` tab heading

Following is the code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-column flex-sm-row" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="events-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#events" role="tab" aria-controls="events" aria-selected="true"> Events</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="personal-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#personal" role="tab" aria-controls="personal" aria-selected="false"> Personal</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="prints-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#prints" role="tab" aria-controls="prints" aria-selected="false"> Prints</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content " id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="events" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="events-tab">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <p> Lorem Ipsum events </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="personal" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="personal-tab">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <p> Lorem Ipsum personal </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="prints"  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="prints-tab">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <p> Lorem Ipsum prints</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example)?

Comment: looks about right. I'll check it. I have not yet read about this component yet. Thank you. Happy to accept this as an answer if it works. Mind changing your comment to an answer?

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the card component for this look.

Check the docs for it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example).